# what are the differences between String method split(String str, int len) and split(String str)?

Tags: java, string, split

```
    String str = "1,2,3,,";
    String[] arr1 = str.split(",");
    String[] arr2 = str.split(",", -1);

    // equals ?false
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepEquals(arr1, arr2));

    // values [1, 2, 3]
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr1));

    // [1, 2, 3, , ]
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr2));
```

Which method should I choose?Give me some advices.

Comment: The secret is buried in the API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String- / https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-

Comment: The method you need to choose depends on what you are going to use the result for.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) says, split(String str, int len) will return a maximum of "len"-1 matches of the pattern "str", so you can set a threshold of how many results you get.

In split without the limit the pattern will be applied as many times as possible.